# Is there a way to use ObjectType in a category on NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, generics

I've been trying to create a category on NSArray and looking at the interface of NSArray I assume that to add a method that returns an ObjectType, is:

```
// interface
- (nullable ObjectType)giveMeAnObject;

// implementation
- (nullable ObjectType)giveMeAnObject
{
    ObjectType object = nil;
    return object;
}
```

However that doesn't work and I get the error message **Expected ')'** in the return type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems you can use lightweight generics in interfaces, but not implementations.

```
@interface NSArray<ObjectType> (MyAdditions)

- (nullable ObjectType)giveMeAnObject; // specify return type

@end


@implementation NSArray (MyAdditions)

- (id)giveMeAnObject // use id for the implementation
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

You might want to file an [enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) if you'd like to see them in `@implementation` blocks too.