# objc covariants implementation syntax

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface NSDictionary<__covariant KeyType, __covariant ObjectType>(String)

-(NSString*)stringForKey: (KeyType)key;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary(String)

-(NSString*)stringForKey: (KeyType)key;
                           ^^^^^^^^ compiler says "Expected a type"
{
    NSString *s = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (![s isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
        s = nil; // guard against trash
    }
    return s;
}

@end
```

What's the proper syntax would be?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to remove ; in method implementation.

Comment: Yes Its cleaner but makes no difference compiler errorwise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use ObjectType in a category on NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673975/is-there-a-way-to-use-objecttype-in-a-category-on-nsarray)

Comment: It seems that it does. Thanks!